# Yield function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return, yield

I basically want to have a function which is GET'ing a page and then returns a result based on that, this leads to the following problem:

All GET methods are using a callback function, meaning that the function will end before the result is there. How do I pause the thread until the callback is fired and then return the result of the callback in my main function?

```
function someFunction(){

$.get(
    "blabla.php",
    function(data) {
        // This data is supposed to be returned by "someFunction"
    }
)

return //the data we retrieved from 'blabla.php'
```

}

How would you accomplish this?

EDIT: I know this concept from lua, however I'm not entirely sure if someone would call it "Yielding a function result". Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Restructure your code so that it works with callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer:  don't.  Asynchronous is the correct way to do HTTP requests.  However, there are cases when you want to block while waiting on a result, so in those cases:

Use the `async` parameter.

```
function somefunction() {
    var retVal;
    $.ajax({
         url:    "blabla.php",
         success: function(data) {
                      // modify data here
                      retVal = data;
                  },
         async:   false
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning something from your function why not just take a callback as an argument?

```
function someFunction(callback) {
  $.get("blabla.php", function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
  // Or simply $.get("blabla.php", callback) if the data need not be modified before calling the callback.
}
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
someFunction(function (data) {
  alert("Data received!");
});
```

JavaScript is single-threaded, so this is really the only reasonable way to accomplish something like this without blocking the entire script.